# Accessing polymer functions from Javascript

Tags: javascript, socket.io, polymer, polymer-1.0

Sorry for the inconvenience caused (my English is not very good and I am using the translator to write this).
I have searched enough looking in StackOverFlow and other sites and I do not find the answer I need.
I am working on a project with Polymer, in which I have declared functions as follows:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'LaserLand-Cronometro',
  properties: {
    jugadores: Object,
    minuto: Number,
    segundo: Number,
    centesima: Number,
    hora:{
      type: String,
      value: '00:00:00'
    },
    task: Number
  },
  cronometro: function(){
    this.centesima++
    if(centesima>99){
      this.centesima=0
      this.segundo++
    }else if(segundo > 59){
      this.segundo=0
      this.minuto++
    }
    let mm;
    let ss;
    let cc;
    if(this.centesima<9){cc='0'+this.centesima}
    if(this.segundo<9){ss='0'+this.centesima}
    if(this.minuto<9){mm='0'+this.minuto}
    this.hora=mm+':'+ss+':'+cc
  },
  evento: function(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

But as I'm working with Socket.io, I need to access them using javascript vanilla, for example:

```
<script>
Polymer({
  is: 'LaserLand-Cronometro',
  properties: {
    jugadores: Object,
    minuto: Number,
    segundo: Number,
    centesima: Number,
    hora:{
      type: String,
      value: '00:00:00'
    },
    task: Number
  },
  cronometro: function(){
    this.centesima++
    if(centesima>99){
      this.centesima=0
      this.segundo++
    }else if(segundo > 59){
      this.segundo=0
      this.minuto++
    }
    let mm;
    let ss;
    let cc;
    if(this.centesima<9){cc='0'+this.centesima}
    if(this.segundo<9){ss='0'+this.centesima}
    if(this.minuto<9){mm='0'+this.minuto}
    this.hora=mm+':'+ss+':'+cc
  },
  evento: function(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
});
var socket = io('http://localhost:7000',{'forceNew': true});
var time;
socket.on('inicio', function(data){
    time = setInterval(cronometro, 100);
});
```

I already tried different ways to do that, but none walks, so I need your help.
In other words, **is there any way to access the functions declared in polymer directly from javascript?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not call this method because there is no instance created yet!

It seems from your code, that you have defined a custom element called '`LaserLand-Cronometro`'. Your method `cronometro` will only be available within an instance of this custom element.
So all you have to do is to create/get an instance of the custom element first and then call its method.

You have to include Socket.io in the Polymer [registration life cycle](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements#lifecycle-callbacks) or create an instance yourself.

```
....
var laserLand = document.createElement('LaserLand-Cronometro');

var socket = io('http://localhost:7000',{'forceNew': true});
var time;
socket.on('inicio', function(data){
    time = setInterval(laserLand.cronometro, 100);
});
```

I might suggest to create a custom-element, that wraps your backend connection via socket.io and provides an API, to bind the data into your polymer app.
Maybe the [firebase elements](https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire) give some inspiration.

Hope this helps.